# Ugly edge prolly needs opacity 0

Tags: javascript, opacity, jquery-hover

I have some round button and when hover it the opacity is 0 and the below div is visible.
But if you might see the edges are not nice, it probably can be solved pritty easy.

How can I have class .b be hidden and when roll over .a then opacity .b = 1?
I think this will solve my problem.

Check my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/8XEaD/1/

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $(".a").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
  }); 
});
```

Comment: how about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/8XEaD/2/

Comment: problem with box-shadow property..Handle that..

Comment: thanks feddus, needed to add <div class="b" style="opacity:0;">

Comment: Fade the green thing out instead of the avatar in.

Comment: prolly -> http://www.internetslang.com/PROLLY-meaning-definition.asp
...anyway a bit useless comment I think James. This is about code and not grammar

Comment: sasi, yea I noticed without the boxshadow the edges are ok.

Answer (score 0):

THanks Feddus, this is what I need

[jsfiddle.net/8XEaD/2](http://jsfiddle.net/8XEaD/2)

just needed to add `<div class="b" style="opacity:0;">`